# CosmicMind/Material SideMenu, how to change viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I am using CosmicMind/Material with a SideMenu, like in this example: [here](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/tree/master/Examples/Programmatic/App), but I can not figure out how to change (load) another view controller when I push a cell of the Menu.

To illustrate, in the example Material/Example/App, I would like to click on "inbox" and load the InboxViewController.

Comment: Checkout this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647528/how-to-implement-a-sidenavigationviewcontroller-into-a-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

To change the mainViewController area of the SideNavigationViewController, use the

```
transitionFromMainViewController
```

method.

You would also need a reference to the SideNav... and to get one from any UIViewController, you can use the Optional property

```
sideNavigationViewController?.transitionFromMainViewController(InboxViewController())
```

That's all it takes.

Comment: It works, but is it possible to have a working example (in Example/App?), so that we can see how to use Material with the best practices, close the menu and so on ..?

Comment: Yeah, I use a NavigationBarViewController as the mainViewController in the example App project. So rather than switch the SideNav, I switch the Nav mainViewController. More examples are coming :)

Comment: Checkout this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647528/how-to-implement-a-sidenavigationviewcontroller-into-a-uiviewcontroller